# String replace not working properly Php

Tags: php

I get a variable which looks like this:

`$var = "User list 1,,User list 3,User list 4,,,,User list 5,,,User list 6"`

My question is how can I display that like below:

```
User list 1
User list 3
User list 4
User list 5
User list 6
```

I tried this: `echo str_replace(",","<br>",$var);`

but I get the wrong output:

```
    User list 1

    User list 3
    User list 4



    User list 5


    User list 6
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Your have back to back `,` in your string that's the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `implode` and `explode` along with `array_filter` like as

```
$var = "User list 1,,User list 3,User list 4,,,,User list 5,,,User list 6";

echo implode("<br>",array_filter(explode(',',$var)));
```

**Output :**

```
User list 1
User list 3
User list 4
User list 5
User list 6
```

**Edited :**

Lets make it more clear stepwise

**Step 1**

We'll exploding string at `,` using `explode` function of PHP like as

```
explode(',',$var);
```

which'll result into

```
Array
(
    [0] => User list 1
    [1] => 
    [2] => User list 3
    [3] => User list 4
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => User list 5
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => User list 6
)
```

Now  we've empty values within array. So we need to remove that empty values using `array_filter` like as

```
array_filter(explode(',',$var));
```

results into an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => User list 1
    [2] => User list 3
    [3] => User list 4
    [7] => User list 5
    [10] => User list 6
)
```

Now as OP stated output must break at new line we'll simply use `implode` along with `<br>` like as

```
echo implode("<br>",array_filter(explode(',',$var)));
```

Results

```
User list 1
User list 3
User list 4
User list 5
User list 6
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/440430)

**Explanation :**
Your attempt

```
echo str_replace(",","<br>",$var);
```

What you were doing over here is replacing each `,(comma)` along with `<br>` which'll simply output your result.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. First replace consecutive spaces with single space and then `explode` on a `single comma` and then `implode` the array on `<br>` tag to form the desired list as follows.

```
$string="User list 1,,User list 3,User list 4,,,,User list 5,,,User list 6";
$string = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $string);
echo (implode('<br>',explode(',',$string)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `explode`

```
$var = "User list 1,,User list 3,User list 4,,,,User list 5,,,User list 6";

$a = explode(',',$var);

foreach($a as $b=>$c)
{
    if(!empty($c))
          echo $c."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
        $var = "User list 1,,User list 3,User list 4,,,,User list 5,,,User list 6";
        $arrvar = explode(',',$var);
        $arrvar = array_values(array_filter($arrvar));
        foreach($arrvar as $key=>$val)
        {

           echo $val."<br>";
        }
```